# Listbox Not Displaying Data (Is Binded With Item Template)

Tags: c#, wpf, list, binding, listbox

I know that this is basically a repeat asked by heaps of people, but I've had difficulty, my combobox lists hdds, when clicked they should fill the listbox with images, thanks to prior help this runs without error except that listbox displays nothing, I have it binded in a item template etc so I'm stuck as to why nothing displays

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;
    }


    private void HDDSelectionBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //ComboBox Lists Local Hardrives 
    {
        string[] drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives(); //Drive Letters, Into A String Array

        foreach (string drive in drives)
        {
            HDDSelectionBox.Items.Add(drive); //Adds Each Drive Letter As A Combox Box Item
        }
    }



    public List<Photos> LoadImages ///List Retrieves and Loads Photos
    {
        get
        {
            List<Photos> images = new List<Photos>();
            if (HDDSelectionBox.SelectedItem != null) //If a item has been selected
            {

                foreach (string filename in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(HDDSelectionBox.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        images.Add( //Add To List
                        new Photos(
                            new BitmapImage(
                                new Uri(filename)),
                                System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)));
                    }
                    catch { ; } //Skips Any Image That Isn't Image/Cant Be Loaded
                }
            }
            return images;

        }
    }

}


public class Photos
{
    private ImageSource _image;
    private string _name;

    public Photos(ImageSource image, string name)
    {
        _image = image;
        _name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _name;
    }

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

   } // END MyImage CLASS
```

}

xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyImageTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image 
               Source="{Binding Image}" Width ="100" Height="100" />
            <TextBlock Text ="{Binding Name}" Width = "100" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>



    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <ListBox
            Name="ImageListBox"
            DockPanel.Dock = "Right"
            ItemsSource = "{Binding LoadImages}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" 
            Width="200"/>
        <ComboBox Width="80" Height="50" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="HDDSelectionBox" Loaded="HDDSelectionBox_Loaded" ></ComboBox>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: be sure this is called `HDDSelectionBox_Loaded`?

Comment: it is, that part is to load local drives which does work, it just clicking on those listed drives does not list anything in the list box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should bind the `ItemsSource` to `SelectedItem` of the combobox and provide some `Converter` to convert the selected item to the corresponding `List<Photo>`. Otherwise you have to notify changes on the `LoadImages` property when the `SelectedItem` of the combobox is changed. Try the following code (modfied in both procedure code and XAML code):

**Code behind**:

```
public class SelectedItemToLoadImagesConverter : IValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture){
        List<Photos> images = new List<Photos>();
        if (value != null) //If a item has been selected
        {
            foreach (string filename in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(value.ToString()))
            {
                try
                {
                    images.Add( //Add To List
                    new Photos(
                        new BitmapImage(
                            new Uri(filename)),
                            System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)));
                }
                catch { ; } //Skips Any Image That Isn't Image/Cant Be Loaded
            }
        }
        return images;
  }
  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture){
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

**XAML code**:

```
<Window.Resources>
  //...
  <local:SelectedItemToLoadImagesConverter x:Key="imagesConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <ListBox
        Name="ImageListBox"
        DockPanel.Dock = "Right"
        ItemsSource = "{Binding ElementName=HDDSelectionBox,Path=SelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource imagesConverter}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" 
        Width="200"/>
    <ComboBox Width="80" Height="50" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="HDDSelectionBox" Loaded="HDDSelectionBox_Loaded" ></ComboBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Note that you can remove the `LoadImages` property in your code. Also note that I used the `local` prefix as reference to namespace of your project in which the class `SelectedItemToLoadImagesConverter` is defined, I hope you know how to define that `xmlns` in your XAML code.

Comment: I've tried your code, i'll investigate into performance, but for the time being it works so thanks heaps! i'll also have to research what is actually happening in the code you gave me because while I understand some, I don't understand everything, but thanks none the less!

Comment: @NathanAnderson I don't think there is any performance issue here, that's how it should be done. The point is when you want to bind something to another thing, you just need to set up the binding directly, if their types don't match each other, we need a `Converter` in between. In this case the source is `SelectedItem`, the target is of course `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would ask you a simple question first: If we ***assume*** you have C: drive only, does the C:\ folder contain any image?

If yes, then we discuss the next problem, which might be in the code.
If no, then obviously, you have nothing to display. But if you have images in sub-folders, you may want to change your use of API `GetFiles`. The right one should get files from all sub-folders:

```
foreach (string filename in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(
                            value.ToString(),
                            "*.png", //assuming that you want PNG images only
                            System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

More about GetFiles, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If this solves your problem, then you may want to enhance it to use enumeration of images, as searching for files in the whole drive may take quite some time, during which your app will be unresponsive.